# JIT code generation for functions and call mechanism

Tags: assembly, compilation, compiler-construction, jit

I'm implementing a simple X86-64 JIT compiler on macOS 10.13 for a simple programming language my question is about the best approach for calling a function in a JIT.

so i will write how i've overcame the problem:

like most compilers i've an AST to help with code generation 
when the code generator find a **function node** *(lets assume that function name is `func`)* it will store a pointer to the current location in the mapped executable memory page then it will generate the rest of the instructions, when this function `func` get called by other function the backend will calculate `Call` instruction operand .

I will be more specific in how i've calculate the operand:

lets assume that the code below was generated by the JIT

```
0000000100000f90 <_func>:
   100000f90:   55                      push   %rbp
   100000f91:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   100000f94:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   100000f95:   c3                      retq   
   100000f96:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   100000f9d:   00 00 00 

0000000100000fa0 <_main>:
   100000fa0:   55                      push   %rbp
   100000fa1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   100000fa4:   e8 e7 ff ff ff          callq  100000f90 <_func>
   100000fa9:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
   100000fab:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   100000fac:   c3                      retq
```

because i've stored the address of `func`**(0x100000f90)** right above
i can calculate the operand of `call` instruction using the formula
Call operand = function Address **(0x100000f90)** - current instruction Address **(0x100000fa4)** - sizeof(`Call`)**(5)** = 0xffffffe7 and because it's intel CPU then it's little endian(0xe7ffffff).

and for every function that will get called that same steps will get used

finally a simple C++ code for the algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sys/mman.h> 

 std::vector<u_int8_t> func{
    0x55,
    0x48,0x89,0xe5,
    0xb8,0x5a,0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x5d,
    0xc3
};

std::vector<u_int8_t> Main{
    0x55,
    0x48,0x89,0xe5,
    0x48,0x83,0xec,0x10,
    0xc7,0x45,0xfc,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xe8,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x48,0x83,0xc4,0x10,
    0x5d,
    0xc3
};

long calculateCallOperand(u_int8_t*funcAddress,u_int8_t*currentAddress){
  return (funcAddress - currentAddress)-5;
}

int main(){
   auto ptr = (u_int8_t*)mmap(nullptr,4096,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC,MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_JIT,-1,0);
   u_int8_t*funcAddress = &ptr[0];

   for(int i=0;i<11;++i)
      ptr[i] = func[i];

  auto operand = calculateCallOperand(funcAddress,&ptr[26]);


  Main[16] = (u_int8_t)operand;
  Main[17] = *((u_int8_t*)&operand+1);
  Main[18] = *((u_int8_t*)&operand+2);
  Main[19] = *((u_int8_t*)&operand+3);


  for(int i=0,j=11;i<Main.size();++i,++j)
       ptr[j]=Main[i];


  auto offset = ptr+11;

  auto call = (void(*)())offset;
  call();
  munmap(ptr,4096);

}
```

(I've run the code and it's working(i don't know if there's any undefined behavior)).

so is this the right way to do it or it's not

if yes is there a better approach
if not what is the right way to do it

I am sorry for the long question but I was trying hard to be clear about my problem , thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably the calls you show are RIP relative, so relative to the current instruction pointer, so that makes it OK.

Comment: Yes it's RIP relative actually x86-32 and x86-64 architecture call instruction is relative to the instruction pointer register, any way thanks for the comment

Comment: Generally it is RIP relative, but absolute 64-bit calls do exist afaik (see e.g. http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html). Anyway it seems fine, but I would align function addresses, as your disassembly does.

Comment: Very interesting I thought that even far calls are relative to RIP any way your assumption is right about that the JIT will only do near calls , thanks for the information

Comment: Terminology: `far call` means changing `CS` as well as `RIP`.  Calling with a displacement larger than `rel32` is *not* a `far` call in x86 terminology, it's simply a 64-bit absolute "near" call.